# Importing different subpackage in same package

Tags: python-3.x

i tried to importing some function but it keep give me error

The file structure is like this:

```
root
|- __init__.py
|- folder a
|   |- __init__.py
|   |- file a.py
|   |- file b.py
|   |- etc
|
|- file c.py
```

How to import from file b.py some function and class from file c.py, i used this command `from file c import Class` in file b and it failed and get this ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: In your example, fileb can't import from filec because python doesn't know whereabouts of filec during the import. The most obvious solution would be to alter your `sys.path` and append the path of the `root` to it, so python knows where to find filec.